# EventHandler and Rectangle JavaFx

Tags: javafx-8

- I don't want to use an anonymous class.
- How can I change / use my EventHandler on the rec ?

ColorswitchClass:

```
public class FarbtestEventHandlerAusserhalb extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane p = new Pane();
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setPadding(new Insets(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 10.0));
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(150.0, 50.0, 100.0, 100.0);
        p.getChildren().add(rec);
        rec.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        
        Button btn = new Button("Farbenwechsel");
        btn.setOnAction(new MyEventHandler());
        
        bp.setCenter(rec);
        bp.setBottom(btn);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(btn, Pos.CENTER);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 300.0, 280);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Farb-Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

MyEvendHandler Class

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class MyEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int rot = (int) (Math.random() * 255.0);
        int gruen = (int) (Math.random() * 255.0);
        int blau = (int) (Math.random() * 255.0);
        FarbtestEventHandlerAusserhalb feha = new FarbtestEventHandlerAusserhalb();
        rec.setFill(Color.rgb(rot, gruen, blau));
    }
}
```

- The Error from Eclipse: rec cannot be resolved
- I want to use the recto change the color

Answer (score 0):

Because, MyEventHandler() doesn't know the "rec". Class MyeventHandler should be as follows,

```
public class MyEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

Rectangle  rec;

public MyEventHandler(Rectangle rec) {
    
    this.rec = rec;
    
}

public void handle(ActionEvent e)
{
    int rot = (int) (Math.random() * 255.0);
    int gruen = (int) (Math.random() * 255.0);
    int blau = (int) (Math.random() * 255.0);
    FarbtestEventHandlerAusserhalb feha = new FarbtestEventHandlerAusserhalb();
    rec.setFill(Color.rgb(rot, gruen, blau));
}
}
```

Usage :

```
 btn.setOnAction(new MyEventHandler(rec));
```